# How to add multiple drag handlers to jQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Ok so the question is, how to add multiple handlers to a draggable dialog.

```
_makeDraggable : function() {
    var self = this, options = this.options, heightBeforeDrag;
    this.uiDialog.draggable( {
        cancel : '.ui-dialog-content',
        handle : '.ui-dialog-titlebar',
        containment : 'document',
        start : function() {
        heightBeforeDrag = options.height;
        $(this).height($(this).height()).addClass("ui-dialog-dragging");
        (options.dragStart && options.dragStart.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
         },
         drag : function() {
        (options.drag && options.drag.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
         },
         stop : function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-dialog-dragging").height(heightBeforeDrag);
        (options.dragStop && options.dragStop.apply(self.element[0], arguments));
         }
    });
}
```

So I have this function, and as you can see it cancels the .ui-dialog-content and ads .ui-dialog-titlebar as handler:

```
this.uiDialog.draggable( {
    cancel : '.ui-dialog-content',
    handle : '.ui-dialog-titlebar',
    containment : 'document',
```

Though, I'd like to add .menu_inner as handler, wondering if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handle` accepts a jquery selector as its parameter. So try using a Multiple selector: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

i.e: `handle: '.ui-dialog-titlebar, .menu_inner'`

edit:
A hacky solution would be to say something like `$('.ui-dialog-titlebar, .menu_inner').addClass('draggable-element')` and then set the handle to that class

Comment: What about without the space?

Comment: dcpomero I've tried without space too, it's kinda tricky, as a workaround I managed to minimize the width as low as possible so it doesn't disable the ability to click on the draggable element. PS. I'm speaking about the TABS from the jQuery Dialog that annoyes the mouse clicks.